# Can we use figcaption element now?

Tags: html

There are still discussions and doubts about whether `<figcaption>` would stay in HTML5 or not. I used it and it seems nice and semantic. Should I stop using it, or can I continue investing on incorporating this element into my projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, personally, I'd wouldn't use it. Not because of the discussions, but because of browser compatibility. For example, IE9 has the worst HTML5 score (according to http://html5test.com/results.html) of any modern web browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.). So, you never know if it might not support HTML5 well. I recommend using Javascript to setup an HTML validation system (or whatever you want to call it). The web page (through Javascript) will figure out the useragent string for the web browser the end-user uses to connect to you site. If the useragent string is one of the ones you listed somewhere in you website, then it will use HTML5. If it's not on the list (or on a no-HTML5 list), it should use standard HTML (4.01).

There are only a few new HTML5 macros that I'm currently using. When HTML5 becomes official, I'll probably start using more of them (because they probably won't change).

Unfortunately, the system I described above (for browser recognition), I have yet to implement (but I am working on a javascript engine that will perform the functions above). I also have no idea how to do it (I'm a javascript n00b). It's just a concept though.

As an alternative, I'd use a regular paragraph element.

Comment: Thank you @Josh, but `feature sniffing` is much more safer than `browser sniffing`. I really appreciate your hard works. But you already have a competitor, [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of "feature sniffing"... I've also never heard of Modernizr. Thanks for the link @Saeed Neamati...

Comment: Then mark it as _great comment_, so others will read this thread more easily. :)